# Bitbucket Pipeline Call via API with parameters

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

I have a bitbucket pipeline that will be triggered from outside:

```
  custom:
    # This Pipeline will be triggered automatically when the setup succeeds
    test-deployment:
      - variables:
          - name: build_number
      - step:
          name: "Test"
          image: atlassian/default-image:latest
          script:
            - echo $build_number
            - export
```

I have to pass the parameter "build_number" to this pipeline and I tried this with the following call:

```
curl -X POST -is -u user:pass \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/pipelines/ \
-d '
{
"target": {
  "ref_type": "branch",
  "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
  "ref_name": "feature/pipeline-tests",
  "selector": {
    "type": "custom",
    "pattern" : "test-deployment"
    }
  }
},
"variables": [
  {
    "key" : "build_number",
    "value" : "202"
    }
  ]
}'
```

But the "build_number" was not set. If I call the pipeline via the Bitbucket UI it works. What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try adding the missing parameter "secured":

```
{
    "key" : "build_number",
    "value" : "202",
    "secured": False
}
```